# proof check composite of linear transformation is invertible given $rank(T) = rank(T^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $T : V → V$ be a linear map, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional
>   vector space. Then $T^2$ is defined to be the composite $T ◦ T$ of $T$
>   with itself, and similarly $T^{i+1} = T ◦ T^i$ for all $i ≥ 1$.
>
> Suppose that $rank(T) = rank(T^2)$.
>
> Prove that $im(T) = im(T^2)$
>
> For $i ≥ 1$, let $U_i: im(T) → im(T)$ be defined as the restriction of
>   $T^i$ to the subspace $im(T)$ of $V$. Show that $U_i$ is nonsingular
>   for all $i$.
>
> Deduce that $rank(T) = rank(T^i)$ for all $i ≥ 1$

I have solved the first part by showing that $im(T^2)$ is a subset of $im(T)$ so the basis of $im(T^2)$ can be extended to that of $im(T^2)$. But since the ranks are equal, they have equal bases.

For the second part my first approach is to proof that $U_i$ is bijective. I think I have a proof for surjectivity by induction. But I can't figure out injectivity. Also I can't figure out the third part.

**Edit 1:**

Proof for surjectivity. First show that $U_1$ is surjective. Suppose otherwise, then there exists $y \in V$ such that $T(T(z)) \neq T(y)$ for any $z \in V$, which contradicts the first part of the question. Now given $U_i$ (/) and $U_1$ (//) is surjective, we have $T_{i+1} = T_1(T_i(x))$ for all $x \in im(T)$ implies $U_{i+1} = U_1(U_i(x))$ by (/). But also by (/) we have that $U_i(x)$ spans the domain of $U_1(x)$ so by (//) $U_{i+1}$ is surjective. This is equivalent to invertible for linear transformations.

Any help with 3?

**Edit 2:**

suppose $im(T^i) = im(T)$

then $im(T^{i+1}) = im(T(T^i)) = im(T(x))$ such that $x \in im(T)$

$ ... = im(U_1) = im(T)$ so same applies to rank.

Comment: If $U^i$ is surjective, then it is bijective simply because its domain and codomain are the same? If your surjectivity proof is fine, then bijectivity should be obvious. You have not shown your surjectivity proof, however(even if it is trivial to you, show it so we can confirm it).

Comment: is this an obvious fact even for infinite sets?

Comment: No, it is not true for arbitrary sets, for example we have a surjection $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ which is not a bijection, namely sending every natural number $x \geq 2$ to $x-1$, and sending $1 \to 1$. However, note that here, we have a linear map with the same finite dimensional vector space as the target, so here we can use  the rank-nullity theorem to show that any surjective map is also injective and therefore bijective.